# (Canvas | Discord.js) I'm trying to set a background using `ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` but the command doesn't work

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

If I use only this code, the command works:

```js
const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./silver.jpg');
```

But I want more than one background for my image. Then, I wrote this code but didn't work :

```js
let backgr;

if (json.items[0].rating < 65) backgr = './bronze.jpg';
else if (json.items[0].rating > 65 && json.items[0].rating < 74) backgr = './silver.jpg';
else if (json.items[0].rating > 75 && json.items[0].rating < 74) backgr = './gold.jpg';

const background = await Canvas.loadImage(backgr);
```

I don't get any error on the console or on Discord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should log what backgr is before you load it, that way you can see what the result is, which might be blank.

Anyways I think the error is within the conditionals, you are using `>` and `<` but never checking for equal, like this:

```js
if(rating < 65) ...
else if (rating > 65 && rating < 74) ...
```

What happens if the rating === 65? It would skip both those statements, and the third one aswell

```js
let backgr;
const rating = json.items[0].rating;

if (rating < 65) {
   backgr = './bronze.jpg';
} else if (rating < 74) {
   backgr = './silver.jpg';
} else {
   backgr = './gold.jpg';
}

const background = await Canvas.loadImage(backgr);
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked the code again and fixed some bug ( like  `... 75 && json.items[0].rating < 74` (because that was wrong)) and I added your Tips!